# How can I give a value to a variable in one Onclicklistener and use that value in another Onclicklistener in Android?

Tags: android

I can't figure out how to fix this problem in my code: I am making a small app which randomly asks you for 20 words from Dutch (nederlands)  to English (engels). I have saved the words in arrays and the words are randomly picked now. There are 2 buttons: One for picking a random word and one for checking if the answer is correct. The variable iwoord is given a random value when pressing button Newword and i want the same value to be used in the next OnClickListener, so I can compare the arrays and see if the answer is correct. But the variable cannot be resolved in the second OnClickListener. Can anybody help me solving my problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText NederlandsEdit;
EditText EngelsEdit;
Button ControleerButton;
Button NieuwwoordButton;
Random woord = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String[] nederlands = new String[20];
        nederlands[0] = "bij";
        nederlands[1] = "paraplu";
        nederlands[2] = "hond";
        nederlands[3] = "kaas";
        nederlands[4] = "eekhoorn";
        nederlands[5] = "fiets";
        nederlands[6] = "auto";
        nederlands[7] = "vis";
        nederlands[8] = "maan";
        nederlands[9] = "aarde";
        nederlands[10] = "vuur";
        nederlands[11] = "boom";
        nederlands[12] = "blaadje";
        nederlands[13] = "soep";
        nederlands[14] = "sok";
        nederlands[15] = "potlood";
        nederlands[16] = "kat";
        nederlands[17] = "muis";
        nederlands[18] = "zeep";
        nederlands[19] = "ring";

   final String[] engels = new String[20];
         engels[0] = "bee";
         engels[1] = "umbrella";
         engels[2] = "dog";
         engels[3] = "cheese";
         engels[4] = "squirrel";
         engels[5] = "bicycle";
         engels[6] = "car";
         engels[7] = "fish";
         engels[8] = "moon";
         engels[9] = "earth";
         engels[10] = "fire";
         engels[11] = "tree";
         engels[12] = "leaf";
         engels[13] = "soup";
         engels[14] = "sock";
         engels[15] = "pencil";
         engels[16] = "cat";
         engels[17] = "mouse";
         engels[18] = "soap";
         engels[19] = "ring";

    NederlandsEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnederlands);
    EngelsEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editengels);
    ControleerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butcontroleer);
    NieuwwoordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butnieuwwoord);

    NieuwwoordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    NieuwwoordButton.setEnabled(false);
    ControleerButton.setEnabled(true);
    int iwoord = woord.nextInt(20 - 0) + 0;
    NederlandsEdit.setText(nederlands[iwoord]); 
    }
});
    ControleerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(EngelsEdit.getText().toString().equals(engels[iwoord])){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
        i = i + 1;  
        }
        }

});
}
```

Comment: Which is the variable that cannot be resolved?

Comment: please post your LogCat and tell us what is the line that gives an error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The int "iwoord" should be declared globally just like the edittexts. I have posted the code just in case.

```
package com.example.stack_test;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText NederlandsEdit;
EditText EngelsEdit;
Button ControleerButton;
Button NieuwwoordButton;
Random woord = new Random();
int i,iwoord;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final String[] nederlands = new String[20];
    nederlands[0] = "bij";
    nederlands[1] = "paraplu";
    nederlands[2] = "hond";
    nederlands[3] = "kaas";
    nederlands[4] = "eekhoorn";
    nederlands[5] = "fiets";
    nederlands[6] = "auto";
    nederlands[7] = "vis";
    nederlands[8] = "maan";
    nederlands[9] = "aarde";
    nederlands[10] = "vuur";
    nederlands[11] = "boom";
    nederlands[12] = "blaadje";
    nederlands[13] = "soep";
    nederlands[14] = "sok";
    nederlands[15] = "potlood";
    nederlands[16] = "kat";
    nederlands[17] = "muis";
    nederlands[18] = "zeep";
    nederlands[19] = "ring";

   final String[] engels = new String[20];
     engels[0] = "bee";
     engels[1] = "umbrella";
     engels[2] = "dog";
     engels[3] = "cheese";
     engels[4] = "squirrel";
     engels[5] = "bicycle";
     engels[6] = "car";
     engels[7] = "fish";
     engels[8] = "moon";
     engels[9] = "earth";
     engels[10] = "fire";
     engels[11] = "tree";
     engels[12] = "leaf";
     engels[13] = "soup";
     engels[14] = "sock";
     engels[15] = "pencil";
     engels[16] = "cat";
     engels[17] = "mouse";
     engels[18] = "soap";
     engels[19] = "ring";

NederlandsEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editnederlands);
EngelsEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editengels);
ControleerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butcontroleer);
NieuwwoordButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butnieuwwoord);

NieuwwoordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
NieuwwoordButton.setEnabled(false);
ControleerButton.setEnabled(true);
iwoord = woord.nextInt(20 - 0) + 0;
NederlandsEdit.setText(nederlands[iwoord]); 
}
});
    ControleerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if(EngelsEdit.getText().toString().equals(engels[iwoord])){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
    i = i + 1;  
    }
    }

});
}

}
```

Comment: This wont work as eclipse will ask him to make iwoord variable final.

Comment: i tried in eclipse, I did not ask to make it final.

Comment: Run your code, get around with it and you'll see :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable globally and you can able assign value from first `onclicklistener` and use it frm the second `onclicklistener`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are facing problems that listeners ask you to make your variable **final**, use a **setter** and a **getter** method for your variable. You cant change the value of an integer variable once you have initialized it for the first time. Don't use it directly in the Listener code, and you wont have to make it final.

Read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) if you need to be familiar with getters and setters.